# In django how can I loop through specific fields in the parent model (user) including some specific fields in the attached child model (userprofile)

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-templates, one-to-one

I have a table in my template, For each individual user in the `User` model, I want to loop through their `username`, `phone`, & `email`. I also want to include from the `Profile` model the user's `age`, `state`, & `address`.

my model classes in `models.py`:

```
class User(models.Model):
    ...
    username = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=True)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
    ...

class Profile(models.Model):
    ...
    users = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True, related_name='userprofile')
    age = models.PositiveIntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    state = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=True)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    profile_pic = models.ImageField(upload_to='profile_pics/', null=True)
    ...
```

my views in `views.py`:

```
...
def registeredUsers(request):
    users = User.objects.all()
    context = {'users': users}
    return render(request, 'users.html', context)
...
```

My template has the table contents below:

```
                     ...
                        </tbody>
                            {% for i in users %}
                            <tr>
                                <td>{{ i.username }}</td>
                                <td>{{ i.phone }}</td>
                                <td>{{ i.email }}</td>
                                <td>{{ i.age}}</td>
                                <td>{{ i.state}}</td>
                                <td>{{ i.address}}</td>
                            </tr>
                            {% endfor %}
                        </tbody>
                     ...
```

The template is only showing the fields in the `User` model, How can I define a view function to make sure that the `User` model pulls the fields of the Profile model with it?

Comment: Use `User.objects.select_related('userprofile').all()` as your queryset, to prevent hitting the DB per user per profile when you iterate in your template, and just use the user in your template the usual way like: `i.userprofile.age`

Comment: Why do you mix the usage of <th> and <td> elements? The <th> is used to hold the title of the row or column, depending on the orientation of the table.

Comment: Thanks @Danijela Popović, it was a typo.

Comment: You're welcome. Even if this seems as a secondary thing for many web developers, it influences pretty much the way the tables are presented to a user with visual impairement. And of course, it isn't a good custom and disobeys the standards, so... well, you catch the point. :) #NoHate

Comment: By the way, shouldn't the table data go inside the <tbody> and not outside of it? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your models defined as they are (I'm mainly speaking about the related_name on Profile.user), write something like this inside your for loop:

```
...
<td>{{ i.userprofile.age }}</td>
...
```

Answer (score 0):

I notice Your `Profile` models have user fields which is OneToOneRelation with `User` models.

So you can loop like this:

```
 ...
                    </tbody>
                        {% for i in users %}
                        <tr>
                            <td>{{ i.username }}</td>
                            <td>{{ i.profile.age }}</td>
                            <th>{{ i.profile.state }}</th>
                             <th>{{ i.profile.address }}</th>
                            <th>{{ i.phone }}</th>
                            <th>{{ i.email }}</th>
                            <td>{{ i.age}}</td>
                            <td>{{ i.state}}</td>
                            <td>{{ i.address}}</td>
                        </tr>
                        {% endfor %}
                    </tbody>
                 ...
```